# How to check and uncheck mat-checkbox based on API response : Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm new to angular 6 ,here I am trying to check and uncheck the mat-checkbox by using the API response .

But I can't get it worked .It's showing all the checkbox as checked even if the API response is **false**.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let data of summary">
   <mat-checkbox checked="{{data?.BUY_NOW_STATUS}}" class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">Buy now</mat-checkbox>
 </div>
```

Here BUY_NOW_STATUS will be either would be  '**true**' or '**false**'.

Can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: Have you tried printing the data?.BUY_NOW_STATUS next to the Buy Now text, in order to debug and see if the data actually correct? Because your way seems fine to me, the only difference I'd make would be to use [checked]="data?.BUY_NOW_STATUS".

Comment: Yes ,I have checked it out response has 'true' and 'false' values only. @saglamcem

Comment: I have to ask, are the true and false values booleans or strings? As in, true or 'true'? Because the checked directive may be working with === and not ==.

Comment: true and false only @saglamcem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer,

in .html

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let data of summary">
   <mat-checkbox [checked]="data.BUY_NOW_STATUS" class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">Buy now</mat-checkbox>
 </div>
```

in summary.model.ts

```
export interface Summary {
   otherprpoperty : type;
   BUY_NOW_STATUS : bool;
   otherprpoperty : type;
}
```

in your .ts

```
summary: Summary[] = []
```

Here you should update the summary from API call.

```
getSummary(){
  this.summaryService.get().subscribe(summary => {
     this.summary = summary; 
  });
}
```